# BizTalk application consuming api changing to TSL 1.0 to 1.2.What is the Required change in BizTalk side?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

In my BizTalk application I am consuming one rest API which is TSL 1.0.

Now API team going t change the TSL 1.0 to TSL 1.2.

I am using BizTalk 2013 R2.

Any change need to do at BizTalk end to call TSL 1.2 API?

Answer (score 0):

As per [Support for TLS 1.2 protocol in BizTalk Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4091110) and the options listed on [3155464 MS16-065: Description of the TLS/SSL protocol information disclosure vulnerability (CVE-2016-0149): May 10, 2016](https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/help/3155464)

You either

1. Programmatically make the send port change to using TLS 1.2.  This can be done either via an End Point behaviour, or by setting it in the Orchestration

or

2. Make the entire BizTalk server use TLS 1.2.  For that see [Unable to connect to BizTalk group after enabling TLS 1.2 and disabling lower versions of SSL and TLS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62793007/unable-to-connect-to-biztalk-group-after-enabling-tls-1-2-and-disabling-lower-ve)  This involves installing the laster CU and the SQL client as per the Microsoft articles.