# Unable to send data using SQL adapter in BizTalk

Tags: sql, adapter, biztalk

We are unable to send the data to SQL database using SQL adapter in BizTalk.
The error we are facing is:

```
error in initializing provider [DBNETLIB]ConnectionOpen(SECCreateCredentials()]SSL Security error
```

We have recently enabled TLS 1.2 and disabled lower versions on both BizTalk and SQL servers.

We checked that SQL server native client version 11 was also installed in both servers.
We have tried creating ODBC connection using SQL serve native client 11 and that also didn't work.

Can you please suggest what is causing the issue and any other changes needs to be implemented.

Comment: Why are you using ODBC connections rather than connecting directly using the adapter?  Are you sure you updated your connection string from SQLOLEDB.1 to SQLNCLI11 ?

Comment: Is this somehow different than your previous question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62793007/unable-to-connect-to-biztalk-group-after-enabling-tls-1-2-and-disabling-lower-ve You haven't even answered there...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to connect to BizTalk group after enabling TLS 1.2 and disabling lower versions of SSL and TLS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62793007/unable-to-connect-to-biztalk-group-after-enabling-tls-1-2-and-disabling-lower-ve)

Comment: Thanks @Dijkgraaf.This solved my problem after changing the connection string