# Add Web Reference - 'The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send' in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, biztalk, web-reference, biztalk-2013r2

Trying to repoint an existing BizTalk 2013 project to write to a new SharePoint 2016 list. The original development had it pointing to an on-prem SharePoint 2010 list, which was built using a Web Reference.

Every time I try to generate a new Web Reference using the standard 'Add Service Reference' method, it gives me the fairly common 'The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send' error.

There's solutions on getting around this were I programatically getting the web reference in c#, but no way to circumvent it via the web reference generated by Visual Studio.

Can anyone recommend a way around this, as I need to get the new web ref configured and up and running to the new azure SP 2016 list.

Comment: The issue is probably that SharePoint is only allowing TLS 1.2, but .Net 4.5 tries lower version of TLS and does not negotiate upwards. , see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62793007/unable-to-connect-to-biztalk-group-after-enabling-tls-1-2-and-disabling-lower-ve

Comment: At a minimum, for Visual Studio, you will have to do the registry key change  that the other answer there mentions, but you will also have to implement the TLS change on BizTalk to get it running in BizTalk

Comment: Thanks mate, that sounds consistent with my other findings.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve it?

Comment: Sure did thanks, I dont have the exact line of code to hand right now, but my manager had a similar issue that he used to circumvent the issue in a different situation.